# DAX - Running Total on measure by month index

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dynamic "table" (created by SUMMARIZE function based on other table) with fields:

- "MonthIndex" - column
- "Forecast%" - measure which depends on some slicer and switch statements

I am trying to set up a running total "x" of "Forecast%" by "MonthIndex" but the runing total does not work - see screenshot.

```
x = CALCULATE (      
   'table'[Forecast%],      
   FILTER (      
      ALL ( 'table'[MonthIndex] ),      
      'table'[MonthIndex] <= MAX ( 'table'[MonthIndex] )  
   )    
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this dax

```
x = CALCULATE (      
   sum('table'[Forecast%]),      
   FILTER (      
      ALL (table),      
      'table'[MonthIndex] <= MAX ( 'table'[MonthIndex] )  
   )    
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this was a solution from my problem.

```
 x = 
    SUMX(
        FILTER(
            ALL('table'),
            'table'[MonthIndex] <= MAX ( 'table'[MonthIndex] )
        ),
        'table'[Forecast%]
    )
```